# How to find constant c in big O notation

Tags: big-o

I need to prove that 5n^2-6n is O(n^2). How to prove? I don't know big O notation much!

As far as I know,In order to prove, we need to find the value of constant C and n0. 
I searched for the answer and I found a solution in internet where they found c=5 where n0>=1. How it comes??? I couldn't figure it out.
Whenever I try, I get c>= (-1)

Comment: When is -1*n^2 > 5n^2-6n?

Comment: I just did some simple calculation as shown in internet. one of it is to divide both side by n^2. therefore I get 5-6/n <= c. if n=1, then c>= (-1).

Comment: If n is 1, yes, but you’re not allowed to pick any particular n. You need to examine what happens as n grows to infinity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need c*n^2 to overtake 5n^2 - 6n after some n. Well, you're in luck, since 5n^2 - 6n > 5n^2 for all positive n, so it's enough for c*n^2 to overtake 5n^2 ... which it does, trivially, with c = 5 (or c = 6 if you want a strong inequality), for all integral n >= 1.

More generally, for a ploynomial function with degree d, the coefficient of n^d is the threshold value. Anything above it will work as a choice for c. Exercise: Prove this!

Comment: is there any common method to find c?

Comment: I'm sorry. I couldn't prove this. I don't know how it works. Any clue?